# JQuery mobile event for loading dynamic JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I have just read through the jQuery Mobile 1.3 API Documentation event handling and a bit lost on the appropriate event to use.

Basically, I would like my APP to load my blog posts with a loading imaging when its first launched using AJAX. I could only think of the following events but not sure which would best suit my need:

```
$( document ).on('pagecreate' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pagebeforecreate' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pagebeforeload' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pagebeforeshow' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pagecreate' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pageinit' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});

$( document ).on('pageshow' , '#blogposts', function () {
    $.ajax({
    //Get data from server
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you could theoretically use any of those, usually the best option is to go with document ready. This way no matter how long or short the response time is whenever the data comes back from the server the DOM is ready to be manipulated/injected with the data. You can bind to this very easily:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        // get data from server
        success: function (data) {
            $('#blogposts').text(data); // or however you want to inject the data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My understanding from SO is that there is a slight performance hit using document.ready

Comment: Technically if you put your JS at the bottom of the page by the time it loads and runs the document would already have been loaded since it loads top to bottom. I don't see any reason not to use `$(document).ready` unless you are actually having **noticeable** performance issues.